# What is the difference between direct reflection and ambient reflection?

Tags: energy, visible-light, reflection

I am not in Physics major, and I wanted to know what is the difference between these two:

1. direct light reflected for the first time (like an object reflecting the light coming from the sun).
2. ambient light reflected for the second time (like an object reflecting the light coming from the sky).

My questions:

- Are there any equations indicating whether an object is lit by direct light from source or just the ambient light?
- Is it possible to get that information from the RGB values captured by a regular camera?
- Is there a good book about light equations?

Thank you

Comment: I think this question needs more focus. For example, are you asking whether there is any difference between a _photon_ that has been reflected once and a photon that has been reflected twice? Or are you asking about the _geometry_ of light rays coming from/reflected from different places?

Comment: @SolomonSlow my question is about the difference between the intensity values of one point (or a surface) when it is lit by specular + diffuse + ambient lights and when it is only lit by ambient light. I am looking for different properties in intensity values between lit and shadowed regions of a scene.

Comment: Re, "Are there any equations...?" The way to ask that question is, "Given that I know $X$, is there any way I can calculate $Y$?"  What is the $X$ in your question? What is it that you know about the scene? Are you asking how to determine the size and shape of the light source just from a single photograph? A photograph of a known scene? or, of any arbitrary scene? I probably can't answer, but I'm guessing that you are asking a hard question. A skilled photographer can look at a photo and _guess_ about the light source, but I don't know of any automated system that makes similar guesses.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I wanted to know what are some characteristics of shadow and non-shadow regions in a single photograph in order to tell them apart. properties like wavelength, intensity, etc. I think the answer is in something like the Phong model.

Comment: Certainly, diffuse light sources will cast diffuse shadows. I'm not a CGI expert. I only know "Phong" as a technique for _rendering_ a 2D image from the _known_ geometry of the scene and the lights. I asked before, do you assume prior knowledge of the geometry of the scene? Without knowing the geometry, the hard part of the problem will be knowing whether some gradation of tone is a shadow, or some change in the orientation of a surface, or some change in the color of a surface, or some non-uniformity of the light source that is projected on to the surface, etc.

Comment: There are techniques for reconstructing a 3-D scene when you have _multiple_ photographs taken from different viewpoints (or better still, from a video shot by a camera that moves around the scene.) But, I'm getting _way_ out of my area of expertise here. I wish you luck.

Comment: @SolomonSlow In this case there is no assumption about the geometry of the scene. I will look for other options. Thank you for your helpful points.